# Optimize retrieving data time in mongoDB with large collection

Tags: java, mongodb, postgresql

I’m searched through google but still cant find any way to resolve my problem. Sorry if I missed something before ask.

My problem is that I have to migrate data from mongoDB to postgresDB. As far as I know it doesn’t have any tool to do this, then I create a tool by Java for my migration job.

To be sure about the integrity of data I divide my data into block, each block is data of one year - I do this divide in my get data query, each time I get 1000 records and next time I skip (1000 x time).  and sort by date.
My query is like this:

`db.collection.find({“dt”: {$gte: 120101000000, $lt: 130101000000}}).sort({“dt”:1}).skip(n * x).limit(n);`

I faced many problems, but now the biggest problem is that get data from mongo to migrate spent too much time, I have to wait over minutes just for one mini block (1000 records) of 1 year block.

My collection records : ~ 220mil, I'm not sure can this call large collection... I’m using mongo-2.10.1.jar lib to do my task.

- Is there any solution for retrieving data from mongo faster.
- Can you give me any idea about my migration solution? Is there any better solution to do this task?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: You can see how many records query use: db.collection.find({“dt”: {$gte: 120101000000, $lt: 130101000000}}).sort({“dt”:1}).skip(n * x).limit(n).explain("executionStats"). Seems there is no index on dt, or index exist but in other ordering.

Comment: first thank for your advice. yes I don have any index for this field, sadly this field exist in 5 others ordering. I wonder that this query is go through all this ordering. I run the explain like you said and has been timeout err.

Comment: you can try to migrate in index ordering if it exists. Or create index dt:1 (it's must be much faster than migrate without it) and then migrate.

Comment: Now It's better. stupid me forgot that I can create index. many thanks for your advice.